# Html.fromHtml(); not working on some devices

Tags: android, html, android-textattributes

I'm using below code on android nougat and it's working:-

```
Html.fromHtml("<strike> " + myText + "</strike"));
```

But on Marshemellow it's not working, i mean the `<strike>` tag.

Is there any way to get working on all devices ?

`myText` is a dynamic text received in recyleView:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final DealsAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final DataDeals feedItem = feedItemList.get(position);
```

Usage :-

```
holder.oldPrice.setText(fromHtml("<strike>" + feedItem.getOldPrice() + "</strike>"));
```

Comment: use this library https://github.com/PrivacyApps/html-textview

Comment: @Ankita come on man, a whole library for just one command line?

Comment: "But on Marshemellow it's not working, i mean the <strike> tag." -- well, you are missing a `>`. I am going to guess that this is a typo in your question. `<strike>` has been supported since the early days of Android. You would need to do more experiments to see exactly where the problem lies. For example, does `Html.fromHtml()` return an object with the `StrikethroughSpan` in the proper place? If not, the manufacturer tinkered with `Html.fromHtml()`, and you would need to create your `Spanned` in some other way.

Comment: @CommonsWare i also used `<del>` and `<s>` but no difference.
i used the method in below answer and didn't make effect. btw why it's work on nougat? , `Is there any way to get working on all devices ?`

Comment: [As I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154836/html-fromhtml-not-working-on-some-devices?noredirect=1#comment79271686_46154836), you need to do more experiments to determine where the problem lies. Is `fromHtml()` not returning the right `Spanned`?

Comment: @CommonsWare yup it's returning the text with out tag effect, btw i debugged on the method and it's receive the value as well with tags, also one other fishy thing is that the debugger go to this line first `result = Html.fromHtml(html);` and reserve to this line `result = Html.fromHtml(html,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);` again, and in the end return `result` with no effect.

Comment: @CommonsWare also tag removed in `result`, that's mean the method worked as well.

Comment: Then create your `Spanned` without using `Html.fromHtml()`. Use `SpannableStringBuilder` or something.

Answer (score 2):

this method is deprecated.

I should use this code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static Spanned fromHtml(String html){
    Spanned result;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
       result = Html.fromHtml(html,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
    } else {
       result = Html.fromHtml(html);
    }
    return result;
}
```

usage:

`fromHtml("<strike> " + myText + "</strike"));`

**EDIT**

Do not forget to close your triangular bracket:

`fromHtml("<strike> " + myText + "</strike>"));`
instead of your: `fromHtml("<strike> " + myText + "</strike"));`

Comment: post `myText` sample

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem where StrikethroughSpan was not working (for some devices) on a TextView inside a RecyclerView item layout. It worked fine on my Pixel OS 8.1, but didn't work on a Nexus 6 OS 7.1.1.

In my case I realised that some constraints in my layout were causing the issue. I changed the way I had implemented the layout a little bit and the StrikethroughSpan started working again. Pay attention to TextViews with wrap_content widths and heights and positioned in a Relative layout. Things that might affect the size of the TextView might be causing this issue. Unfortunately I didn't get to the root cause of the problem, but I hope this might help other people with similar problems.

As a note, both solutions to strike through the text work for me:

```
Html.fromHtml("<strike> " + myText + "</strike"));
```

or

```
SpannableStringBuilder spanText = new SpannableStringBuilder("my_awesome_text");
spanText.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 0, textToBeDisplayed.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
myTextView.setText(spanText);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Vyacheslav has mentioned, please check that no Font Family is set on your TextView. I spent nearly 4 hours debugging this issue and removing the FontFamily from the TextView solved my issue.